# How to make action (hide) on all table cells, which ID is not containing some string

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I got whole table, which has cells with particular ID's, example: "2012-01-01_841241" etc etc. Date, then some number.

I want to filter my table, so I send some request and get for example three numbers which should be only shown.

I want to hide all cells without these numbers in their IDs - is it any other way than iterating over all of them and check if their ID matches my ID string? (It looks costly).

So, i'm trying to avoid it (especially, when I will have a table of someNumbers :) ):

```
$('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") != someNumber) $(this).hide();
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are yours IDs unique? Because they should be. `$('td#' + someNumber).hide();`

Comment: changing class is more performant than hide/show along with a simple css rule for `td.hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a way you can do it ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/33QjR/1/)):

Essentially you can hide everything then make the ones you want visible:

```
 $("#myTable td").hide();
showCells("2012-01-01_841242", "2012-01-01_841247");

function showCells() {
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)   
 {
     $("#" + arguments[i]).show();
 }
}
```

The problem however with doing this on a table is that you can end up with an uneven number of `<td>` tags inside your various `<tr>` tags so you may want to find a different way to lay them out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider something like this:
You can alway hide all tds and than show only these which you want to show

```
var id = getCurrentIdNotToHide();
$('td#'+id).show();
```

But I'm not sure if this is better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$('td:not([id="' + someNumber + '"])').hide();
```